# Paymant value in form is hanging down when select "Type of journey" second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi guys iv got main problem and two less.

1. When select "Type of journey" option "1-company trip" or "2-personal trip" and set rest values its all ok, ajax is automaticly loading "Value per km" as 1$ or 0.5$ and calculate Paymant value properly, but when "Type of journey" is set from 1 to "3-real cost" and back to 1, Paymant input is hang down. It looks like  script is doing only first time calculations or something. Its working when (Bin2 How many km) value is changed to diffrent value than it was before.
2. Got error in Chrome console `"ReferenceError: onChange is not defined"` and i think that is about line `"$('#trip_realCost').change(onChange).keyup(onChange);"` coz when i delete it, error is not poping up. But why this error is shown when script is still working? Do i need care about that error?
3. Need to click to anywhere in form to calculate values - this is not automaticly after typing some values, but script have onChange action. Do i need to set some trigger or something?

Here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adekk/zmrxeyh7/42/)

This is my first js script and first question in StackOverflow.
Thank you for checki'n it!

Comment: 2. You need to set your JSFiddle JavaScript load type to "no wrap, bottom of `<body>`" 3. use the `input` event instead of `change`

Comment: It was so simple, both are working as you said, thank you. If somebody have solution for 1 thanks in advance.